# Convert party object to pmml

Tags: r, converters, rpart, party, pmml

I am currently trying to convert a decision tree created using the R package partykit (party object) to a pmml-format. Are there packages that allow for this conversion? I am aware of the existance of the pmml-package, but this only supports rpart objects, created using the R package rpart. As I want to create decision trees myself and not retrieve them from a dataset, simply using rpart instead of partykit is not a solution.

Thank you for your suggestions, 
Niels

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the `partykit` package does not provide this feature. The package has many converters from other objects *to* `party` objects, including a converter from PMML. However, there are not many options to convert *from* `party` objects to other classes. A PMML export would certainly nice to have (at least for the special case of `constparty` objects) but so far I didn't look at what needs to be done for this.